# How can I receive image/* data in my HomeFragment using Navigation Component in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to add functionality to my app in which user can share images from other apps to my app.

In my manifest file:

```
      <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
```

So I came across [this documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive). The problem is that it don't tell how can I receive that intent into my fragment. I am using navigation component. And I want to handle the image data in my `HomeFragment` instead of my `MainActivity`